# Broadcom b4313 not works

Tags: wireless, broadcom

There is wireless in network-manager, but not connect with WiFi-router. WiFi networks don't find to.

`uname -a`:

```
Linux alex-Lenovo-B570e 3.5.0-26-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 8 23:18:20 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`iwconfig`:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

eth1      IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

`rfkill list`:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`lspci -vnn -d 14e4`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:051b]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at d0500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: wl, bcma
```

`find /lib/modules/`uname -r`-name '*.ko' | grep wireless`:

```
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/airo.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/mwl8k.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/libertas/libertas.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/libertas/usb8xxx.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/libertas/libertas_spi.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/libertas/libertas_sdio.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/libertas/libertas_cs.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/p54/p54usb.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/p54/p54common.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/p54/p54spi.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/p54/p54pci.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/brcm80211/brcmsmac/brcmsmac.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/brcm80211/brcmutil/brcmutil.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/brcm80211/brcmfmac/brcmfmac.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ipw2x00/libipw.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ipw2x00/ipw2100.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ipw2x00/ipw2200.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/mwifiex/mwifiex_pcie.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/mwifiex/mwifiex_usb.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/mwifiex/mwifiex.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/mwifiex/mwifiex_sdio.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/hostap/hostap_cs.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/hostap/hostap_pci.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/hostap/hostap_plx.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/hostap/hostap.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtl818x/rtl8180/rtl8180.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtl818x/rtl8187/rtl8187.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/atmel.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlegacy/iwl3945.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlegacy/iwlegacy.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlegacy/iwl4965.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ti/wlcore/wlcore_sdio.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ti/wlcore/wlcore.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ti/wlcore/wlcore_spi.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ti/wl12xx/wl12xx.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ti/wl1251/wl1251_sdio.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ti/wl1251/wl1251_spi.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ti/wl1251/wl1251.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192cu/rtl8192cu.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192se/rtl8192se.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192de/rtl8192de.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192c/rtl8192c-common.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192ce/rtl8192ce.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/zd1201.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/wl3501_cs.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/mac80211_hwsim.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rndis_wlan.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/atmel_cs.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt73usb.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2x00lib.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2x00pci.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt61pci.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2x00usb.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2800lib.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2500usb.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2400pci.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2500pci.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2800pci.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2800usb.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/zd1211rw/zd1211rw.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwmc3200wifi/iwmc3200wifi.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/adm8211.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ray_cs.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/airo_cs.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/b43legacy/b43legacy.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/orinoco/orinoco.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/orinoco/orinoco_nortel.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/orinoco/orinoco_usb.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/orinoco/orinoco_plx.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/orinoco/orinoco_tmd.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/orinoco/spectrum_cs.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/orinoco/orinoco_cs.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/b43/b43.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath5k/ath5k.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath6kl/ath6kl_core.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath6kl/ath6kl_sdio.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath6kl/ath6kl_usb.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/carl9170/carl9170.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_hw.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_common.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_htc.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/libertas_tf/libertas_tf_usb.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/libertas_tf/libertas_tf.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/atmel_pci.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/at76c50x-usb.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/tty/ipwireless/ipwireless.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/net/wireless/lib80211_crypt_tkip.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/net/wireless/lib80211_crypt_ccmp.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/net/wireless/lib80211.ko
/lib/modules/3.5.0-26-generic/kernel/net/wireless/lib80211_crypt_wep.ko
```

`sudo iwlist eth1 scan:`

```
eth1      Interface doesn't support scanning : Invalid argument
```

`dmesg | grep -e wl -e eth1`:

```
[   26.975698] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[   27.136694] INFO @wl_cfg80211_attach : Registered CFG80211 phy
[   27.242344] eth1: Broadcom BCM4727 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.20.155.1 (r326264)
[   31.754180] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[   35.100996] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[   58.103251] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[   91.107992] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[  130.258875] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[  133.118953] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[  156.123379] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[  169.119180] ERROR @wl_dev_intvar_get : error (-1)
[  169.119191] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_tx_power : error (-1)
[  189.126384] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[  411.166980] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[  474.181995] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[  537.180742] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[ 1041.020134] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[ 1090.432811] ERROR @wl_dev_intvar_get : error (-1)
[ 1090.432822] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_tx_power : error (-1)
[ 1104.003465] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
[ 1166.980306] ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
```

Comment: Please add: lsmod | grep -e b43 -e wl

Comment: lsmod | grep -e b43 -e wl:

wl                   3074773  0 
cfg80211              206797  1 wl
lib80211               14382  2 lib80211_crypt_tkip,wl

Comment: Looks perfectly normal. Now let's see: dmesg | grep -e wl -e eth1 as well as: sudo iwlist eth1 scan

Comment: I add result thist commands

Comment: I install bcmwl-kernel-source_6.20.155.1+bdcom-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb. And now wireless in network-manager shown, but there is no wifi netwoks. b43, b43legacy and other drivers I remove. Why is it don't work???

Comment: Is the switch set to enable wireless? rfkill list all. Does it scan? sudo iwlist eth1 scan.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the drivers for your wireless interface (`BCM4313`, as you mentioned).

Hook your computer up to a working ethernet connection. Then do the following:

1. Open up `System Settings`.
2. Click on `Additional Drivers`
3. Install the listed proprietary driver for your wireless interface.

Hope that solved your problem!

Comment: There is not "Additional drivers" in system settings. I try: jockey-gtk

"jockey-gtk is not Installed. You may try: sudo apt-get install jockey-gtk."

 When I try install it, I get: "jockey-gtk installed." 

I was download and install: bcmwl_kernel-source_6.20.155.1+bdcom-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb.

Comment: Weird. Are what Ubuntu are you running? 12.04? `Additional Drivers` should definitely be there.

Comment: I running Mint Maya. When wifi wasn't start work, I was upgrade sysrem to linux mint Nadya. In Maya additional drivers works perfect, but in Nadya it's not running.

Comment: I know very little about Mint. I suspect the errors above are what is preventing a connection. You might try reinstalling the driver. With a temporary wired ethernet connection, do: sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source. Reboot and see if there is any improvement.

Comment: I reinstall drivers already for two weaks. Mint - is a fork ubuntu. It's shown in "uname -a"